# Add to UpdatePanel then call Update from another function C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to have a button that adds controls to an update panel and then another button that will update the panel. However, the controls do not show up when I call the update.

For example,

```
     public void Test1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label myLabel= new Label();
        myLabel.Text = "Test";
        UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(domainLabel);
    }

    public void Test2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         UpdatePanel1.Update(); // this doesnt make the label show up
    }
```

I have set UpdateMode as conditional so shouldnt the update panel show the controls i have added after calling Update()?

This is for ASP.NET Web Application

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the dynamic TextBox? Instead add it declaratively and make it visible in Test1_Click. All dynamic controls must be recreated on postback. That's the reason why it doesn't show up in the other button's click-event handler, it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I was just using it as an example, I'm trying to let the user add as many things as they want